# Peugeot PX-10 with Shimano 105 Triple with BB-6700

Tags: shimano, crankset

Upgrading my french PX-10e with shimano 105 cranks. What bottom bracket can I use with this 68mm bottom bracket with french threading?  Is there a threadless BB available?

Answer (score 1):

Velo-Orange makes [threadless](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/grand-cru-threadless-bottom-brackets.html) BB's and [French threaded](http://store.velo-orange.com/index.php/grand-cru-bottom-brackets-hollow-axle-alloy-cups-1121.html) BB's under their Grand Cru line. There is always also [Phil Wood](http://www.philwood.com/products/bbhome.php) if you're rolling in money. They are all JIS (square) tapered. Some other companies (like Stronglight) have also made threadless bb's (for frames which typically have had their threads ruined) in the past - I don't know if this is current.

I'm not entirely sure what BB-6700 has to do with this, though.

I think I see why BB-6700 may be there - you're trying to get a hollowtech/octalink/some other type of setup going. As far as I know, nobody makes a product which will allow you to do this.

You'd either:

- have to force some other BB on there and ruin the threads for the BB
- take the frame to a frame builder and see if they can do some magic to get one of these things in.

Shimano does still make new cranksets which are JIS tapered in the Sora line, but if you want something fancier, you'll have to go with an older used crankset. You can always get nice new replacement chainrings if they're a bit worn.

Edit: Just saw [the outboard bottom bracket](http://www.philwood.com/products/bbpages/outboard.php) page from Phil Wood. Its expensive, but I think it may work depending on the crankset you want to use.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to fit a Shimano 105 Octalink crank. None of the velo orange bbs are compatible like I was counting on.  Dang, I wanted the triple for hill climbing.  Thanks for a good answer, just not the one I was looking for.  Ted

Comment: I updated the bottom of the post so I don't know if you saw it. However, if you sold the 105 crankset, you could probably put in a little more money and get a Shimano triple and a velo orange crankset (certainly cheaper than the two phil wood options posed). This of course assumes you have a triple derailleur and chainline and stuff work out. Alternatively, a double with a different cassette in the back may solve your problem as well.

Comment: Thanks for the additional comments.  Will confirm the Outboard Phil Wood system will fit the crank I have.  Other suggestion also  good.  Awesome website!  Ted